# CodeIgniter pass variable from controller to view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, model-view-controller

Sorry if this question is already been answered, but i couldn't find an answer.
I want to pass a variable from my model to the controller and finally display it in the view.

I execute a query on the database and after that I count my results (via num_rows). Then I return the result.

```
public function countHighRisk(){
    $this->db->select("ares_status");
    $this->db->from("tbl_alert_result");
    $this->db->join('tbl_status_standards', 'ares_status = sts_status_id');
    $this->db->where('sts_status_risk', 3);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

After that i place the result in an array and pass the array to my view.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Alert_result_model');
    $data['high'] = $this->Alert_result_model->countHighRisk();

    $this->load->view('templates/head');
    $this->load->view('templates/menu');
    $this->load->view('pages/Dashboard', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

I get an error when I try to display the variable in the view.

```
<div class="col-xs-8 text-right">
     <span> High Risk </span>
     <h2 class="font-bold"><span class="count"><?= $high; ?></span></h2>
</div>
```

error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cvLO.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the value is getting on the controller by print_r($data['high']); exit;

Comment: can you check if `$this->Alert_result_model->countHighRisk();` returns correct variable

Comment: echo $data['high']; after the database call...is that printing any value;?

Comment: IS YOUR QUERY RETURNS ANYTHING? check it first IS YOUR QUERY RIGHT ? try `echo $this->db->last_query();exit;` below `$query`

Comment: Thank you guys, for the fast response. Apparently there is nothing wrong with the code. I just restarted my localhost and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Your whole idea of calling the views is wrong here. Please use it as follows:

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Alert_result_model');
    $data['high'] = $this->Alert_result_model->countHighRisk();

    $this->load->view('pages/Dashboard', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
<? $this->load->view('templates/head'); ?>
<? $this->load->view('templates/menu'); ?>
<div class="col-xs-8 text-right">
     <span> High Risk </span>
     <h2 class="font-bold"><span class="count"><?= $high; ?></span></h2>
</div>
<? $this->load->view('templates/footer'); ?>
```

Also check what `$this->Alert_result_model->countHighRisk();` is actually returning by doing `print_r($this->Alert_result_model->countHighRisk();)`

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is already fixed. There was no error in my code. I just restarted localhost. 

But are you saying that I have to call other views in a view? In the documentation of codeigniter they say that you have to call multiple views in the controller. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: I am not really fan of code igniter _documentation_, but yeah, its a bit messy when you are calling 3 static lines over and over again in controllers, so why not just call them in views instead. Remember documentation is not `word of God` :)

Comment: The documentation you shared is just an example, which is not architecturally correct in 90% of the cases.

Comment: Thanks, I agree it looks a bit messy. So I will do it like you say :)

Answer (score 1):

You can load a view into controller but do this way below

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
 public function index() {

  $this->load->model('Alert_result_model');
  $data['high'] = $this->Alert_result_model->countHighRisk();

  // Choose only one header examples:
  $data['header'] = $this->load->view('header', Null, TRUE); // If No Data
  $data['header'] = $this->load->view('header', $data, TRUE); // If Data

  // Choose only one Footer examples:
  $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('footer', Null, TRUE); // If No Data
  $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('footer', $data, TRUE); // If Data

  $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
 }
}
```

**Dashboard View**

```
<?php echo $header;?>

<?php foreach ($high as $low) { ?>

   <?php echo $low['something'];?>

<?php }?>

<?php echo $footer;?>
```

If you have a header separate header controller and footer controller you will need HMVC if you are confused on user guide top right corner of default user guide in CI3 is a switch to more cleaner version.

Comment: i have read the article about how to pass data From Controller To View In CodeIgniter 
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-pass-data-in-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

please change

```
$this->load->view('pages/Dashboard', $data);
```

into

```
$this->load->view('pages/Dashboard', $data, true);
```

now it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but this was not necessary I just restarted my localhost and now it works just fine.